VNC server prevents logging in physically on Ubuntu 22.04
This is my setup:

Kubuntu 22.04
Tigervnc 1.13.1

The only configurations I changed in tigervnc are setting display :1 to my user in vncservers.users and forcing localhost in vncserver-config-defaults. Then I started the vncserver using systemd.
When I start the server, if I attempt to login physically to the PC (aka display :0), it will show the cursor with black screen. When I stop the server, I can login physically and use the desktop.
I didn't have this behavior in Kubuntu 20.04 and Tigervnc 1.11.0. I was able to use the physical PC (display :0) and the vnc server (display :1) at the same time back then (a few weeks ago).
I had a look at the changelog of tigervnc, and it doesn't seem they documented any such change between 1.11 to 1.13. Maybe it is a change in ubuntu 22 to prevent multiple displays per user?
Is there anyway to allow the physical display and the vnc display to work at the same time in my setup?
